# Proximity detection between iPhone and android (sleep mode)

Tags: android, iphone, detection, proximity

I'm trying to detect with an android mobile, if my iphone is in the room or not. The use case is the following: when I leave my house (with my iphone in the pocket) the android mobile detect that the iphone is too far, and launch the security service. When I come back home, it will detect my iphone, switch off the alarm and say "Hello"

The main problem is that when my iphone is my pocket, it's in "sleep" mode and in this case, I can't detect the bluetooth. I know that it must be possible, it's same use as new cars which when you enter, it detect your iphone and sync all your data.

Does somebody have an idea to solve my problem? Thanks

Math

Answer (score 0):

Write a Service, or whatever it's called on iPhone, to activate bluetooth every 5 seconds, so the phone in your home can detect it. It will drain your phone's battery very quickly, I guess.

Comment: Yes, this will drain the battery very quickly. 
Try to choose not that frequent intervals.

Comment: With less frequent polling, he will be in the house before the phone switches off the alarm. Of course, if you're willing to spend a lot of time here, you can extrapolate gps fixes and use motion sensors to predict the time you get home, so you can set a timer to approximately the right time. You set the timer early, so it's in time to make a better guess, the system will approach the homecoming asymptotically.

Comment: Ohh, yeah, I forgot. You're right, the polling need to be this frequent. 
I would suggest to use NFC Tags for this scenario, but its an iPhone. 
Another idea is to send a message to the android phone if the iPhone leave a specific GPS area.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I guess it's not very good to activate the bluetooth every 5 sec in the way that I will only leave my house twice a day (maybe sometimes more but not a many times).

I don't really know the NFC tags, that could be an idea, but I guess I need to put the reader near the door and I would have to scan before I could enter. 

The other solution with GPS area is very interesting, I have another question. Is the GPS precision enough for a small area? I don't want to set a big area to be sure that it will work.